# Why can't I apply the same UIView instance to two separate UITextFields without a memory leak?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, memory-leaks

I'm really asking why there's a memory leak in the first place.

I have a view controller with two simple `UITextField` objects. I wanted some left indentation so I'd applied the following to them after creating an `IBOutlet` for both:

```
var textFieldIndentation = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 0))
self.usernameField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
self.usernameField.leftView = textFieldIndentation
self.passwordField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
self.passwordField.leftView = textFieldIndentation
```

After around 15 seconds I've noticed my application has taken more than 1.5GB of RAM and it has been using 100% of the processor non-stop.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the same `UIView` instance as the `leftView` for both `UITextField` objects. Since you have set the `leftViewMode` to `Always`, it will repeadetly remove the `textFieldIndentation` object from one `UITextField` instance in order to add it to the other `UITextField` instance.

Simply do

```
var textFieldIndentationU = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 0))
var textFieldIndentationP = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 0))
self.usernameField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
self.usernameField.leftView = textFieldIndentationU
self.passwordField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
self.passwordField.leftView = textFieldIndentationP
```